# How to detect side mouse-buttons in C#?

Tags: c#, events, event-handling, mouse, mouseevent

I am trying to write a C# program for my [Razer Naga](http://store.razerzone.com/store/razerusa/en_US/pd/productID.169418900) but I am having trouble detecting side mouse-buttons. In the MouseDown event handler it catches M1, M2, MMB, but none of the 12 on the left hand-side near the thumb.

Is there any way to detect these thumb-buttons being pressed?

Thanks.

Comment: This link might help you. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/ReprogramYourMouse.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The side buttons on the Naga are just mapped to the number keys, as well as minus and plus, etc. So most likely you want some sort of keydown or other proper key related event.

Comment: Ah. Good call. I'll just use KeyDown events instead.